# enable and disable a bootstrap button based on value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable and enable bootstrap button based on value.
Here is my code:

```
<table id="userTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="address" items="${addresses.userAddresses}" varStatus="loop">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${address.lastName}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${address.firstName}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${address.address}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <c:out value="${address.isUpdateable}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnbutton" onclick="location.href='/project/update/${loop.index}'" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="address" action="/project/delete/${loop.index}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-title="Delete Address" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this address?');">Delete</button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

based on ${address.isupdateable} value i have to enable /disable the edit button. I tried many ways , i used disabled attribute and I used jquery function but nothing is working.can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly using JQuery did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can try something like

```
<button id="btnbutton" onclick="location.href='/project/update/${loop.index}'" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="visibility: hidden">Edit</button>
```

as an attribute for the button tag. Observe the `style="visibility: hidden"` property

Using Javascript and based on your requirement, you can use

`document.getElementById("btnbutton").style.visibility="hidden"`

To enable, use

`document.getElementById("btnbutton").style.visibility="visible"`

Hope this helps...

**Update - 1:**

Try this.. It must work

Replace the button with following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test= "${address.isupdateable.equals("true")}">
        <button id="btnbutton" onclick="location.href='/project/update/${loop.index}'" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
    </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <button id="btnbutton" onclick="location.href='/project/update/${loop.index}'" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>>Edit</button>
</c:otherwise>
```

Comment: where do I add a condition . I have to check like this {address.isUpdateable} == true enable ,else ,disable

Comment: I tried this. It worked . Thank you to all for your quick responses.

Comment: @hanu glad to help. Mark this as answer if it worked. This helps others looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(${address.isUpdateable}=true){ //update this with whatever your rule is
$('#btnbutton').prop('disabled', true); //change the ID to disable whatever button you want.
}
});
```

Not sure what values `${address.isUpdateable}` can have (text or numeric). So, you may need to also save this value as a variable and then use that in your logic/`if` statement.

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if($(address.isUpdateable)== "false"){
    $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else{
   $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled', false);
  }  
 });
  </script>

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if($(address.isUpdateable)== "false"){
    $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else{
   $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled', false);
  }  
 });
  </script>

Comment: I added like this but it is enabling for all the list.

Comment: My guess is that `$(address.isUpdateable)` isn't the value you think it is. You can also try this: ` if($(address.isUpdateable)= false)` No quotes around false and only one equal sign. You should also check the value of  `$(address.isUpdateable)` with `console.log($(address.isUpdateable))`.

Comment: I used this to assign a value <c:set var="flag" value="${address.isUpdateable}"/>

Comment: in document.ready(function) I added if($(flag)){
  console.log($(flag));
    $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled',false);
  }
  else{
    console.log($(flag));
     $('#btnbutton').prop('disabled',true);
  }

Comment: Is this `${address.isUpdateable}` just a string or supposed to represent some other value? That is, are you just trying to set the value as this actual string `${address.isUpdateable}`?

Comment: in the console I am getting flag is not defined error.

Comment: all firstname,lastname,email,isUpdateable edit,delete all are in a loop. Is because of the loop the document.ready function not having value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***onLoad*** function from ***Jquery***. Read the calue that you wanto to use to get if its disabled or enabled, here is an example:

```
$(function() {
    var isupdateble = ${address.isUpdateable}; //here get your value!
    if(!isupdateble){
        $("#btnbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Or test it in [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/1ecj0ayv/)

Comment: <script>
 $("#btnbutton").load(function() {
 var isupdateble = ${address.isUpdateable};
 console.log(isupdateable) //here get your value!
    if(!isupdateble){
        $("#btnbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  
  });  
</script>

Comment: I added this code but when I run in the browser console it is showing like this $("#btnbutton").load(function() {
 var isupdateble = ;
 console.log(isupdateable) //here get your value!
    if(!isupdateble){
        $("#btnbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }how do I get that address.isUpdateable value?